# Orika Bean Mapper Spring Data ManyToMany join table overriding

Tags: mysql, spring, many-to-many, spring-data-jpa, orika

In my Spring project I have domain and model layer separately. Domain layer are just entities, that maps to tables in MySQL db. Models are used in service layer. I have two tables: User and Roles, that have ManyToMany relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="users", cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<RoleEntity> roles;
//..Getters Setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class RoleEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String value;
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") )
    private List<UserEntity> users;
}
```

Model

```
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Role> roles;
}

public class Role {
    private Long id;
    private String value;
    private List<User> users;
}
```

Repository Layer

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long>{

}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
    MapperFacade mapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();

    public void save(User user) {
        userRepo.save(mapper.map(user, UserEntity.class));
    }

    public User getUser(Long id) {
        return mapper.map(userRepo.findOne(id), User.class);

    }
}
```

The problem is - each time I retrieve user, and update it properties (name for example), and than save back it into table, row in the join table user_role, overrides too. For example if it was

> id=1, user_id=1, role_id=1

, than after update it becomes

> id=2, user_id=1, role_id=1

.

```
@Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        User user = userService.getUser(1L);
        user.setName("kyk");
        userService.save(user);
    }
```

It works correct without mapper, so mapper is the reason. And I can't get any workaround. Has any one faced the same problem? Will be thankful for any help.

Comment: How come your `user_role` table has an `id` column of its own? If it's just a join table, it should only have `user_id` and `role_id` columns.

Comment: @AdamMichalik didn't know about that, thanks. Will fix it. But still, is it okay to update join table row each time I save updated `user`?

Comment: It should not be happening, so you are right to ask about it. Hard to say why, so try dropping the `id` column and see if that helps in anything.

Comment: @AdamMichalik dropped `id` column. Join table still updates, when saving updated user. I think the reason is mapper. When saving those entities,  that are mapped into models and back, there still is `id` that identifies those entities, and allow them to be merged. That seems to be opposite for join table - when saving `user` and `role` entities, no `id` is provided for `user_role` table, so it does not merge it.